# How can I uncomment ";extension=php_openssl.dll" via php script(during runtime)?

Tags: php

I'm using PHPMailer to mail updates to my users from my site. I've no access to php.ini file in that server. Whole PHP works fine in localhost but says, "Could not connect to SMTP host" on my hosting server. 
Please Help! And I'm very new to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function for enabling extensions during runtime: [**`dl()`**](http://php.net/manual/function.dl.php).

> dl - Loads a PHP extension at runtime

*On shared hosters this function is often deactivated!

Since PHP 5.3 dl() was disabled in some SAPI's but not for CLI, CGI and Embed mode.*

In the php.ini you can activate `dl()` by setting [`enable-dl`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.enable-dl)

Answer (score -1):

After your PHP is running, even if you could uncomment the config line it wouldn't cause the lib to load. Similarly you can't override this via .htaccess

But you can load extensions at runtime using the [dl() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) but note that it is usually disabled by default on PHP SAPIs since at least v5.3 - and if you're working in a restricted environment (such as a shared host / managed host) it will likely be disabled there too regardless if it's SAPI/CGI/fCGI for security reasons. Even where the binary has been compiled with dl support, it must be explicitly enabled in the php.ini

> "Could not connect to SMTP host"

Are you sure you need the php openSSL extension to address this?

If you just need support for ssmtp between your PHP code and the MTA, it might be a lot less painful to simply run stunnel. However this presupposes that you need to use SMTP - you didn't say what OS this is running on.

Comment: it would be nice if you at least advised OP to check phpinfo() first - it is not clear that the extension is really missing.

Answer (score -1):

PHPmailer does not use SMTP settings in php.ini. You should set it through its own methods. See [this post](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/) for further instructions and make sure you use the correct settings. The post talks about GMail, but it can be used for other accounts too.

**UPDATE**: source of the problem could be a restrictive firewall on server too.

**UPDATE2**: I highly doubt that missing openssl extension is the cause for your problems. Can you please tell us why you think so? I have hosted on many shared hosts and have used PHPmailer without problems. If in doubt, create and check a page with this content:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

It should list your extensions (if `phpinfo()` is not disabled on host).
Also, you could try using SMTP without SSL/TLS authentication to see if this is really the source of the problems. If it is, you have no choice but to convince / replace your service provider.

Comment: No, it doesn't use the PHP SMTP handler, but it *does* use the openssl functions for encapsulating it's own SMTP protocol stack

Comment: @symcbean: Please elaborate on why you think the problem is in openssl. I very much doubt the problem is in this extension, the usual error message for missing openssl would be "undefined function" or sth. like that. OP is a bit unclear as to what works on localhost, but since he has no experience in PHP, it could be wrong settings too.

Comment: because that is explicitly what Unknown100 stated the problem is.

Comment: Actually, he proposed a partial solution (extension=...) that does not (IMHO) address the symptoms he described (PHPMailer could not connect to SMTP host). But until we get some feedback from OP we will not be able to tell more.